# What T-SQL standard is adhered to in this query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, substring, ssms

I was checking my understanding of SUBSTRING in SSMS version 2008.

I didn't know if start_expression was 0 or 1 based, and if it was 0 based, I didn't understand the purpose of allowing a start_expression of 0.

I ran the query;

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(5) = 'Hello'

SELECT @Test, SUBSTRING(@Test, 1, 4), 'What the ' + SUBSTRING(@Test, 0, 5) + '?',  + SUBSTRING(@Test, -1, 6)
```

which produced the results;

> Hello   Hell    What the Hell?     Hell

Now SQL Server 2008 BOL states;

> start_expression   Is an integer or bigint expression that specifies
>   where the returned characters start. **If start_expression is less than
>   0**, an error is generated and the statement is terminated. If
>   start_expression is greater than the number of characters in the value
>   expression, a zero-length expression is returned.

Even later versions of 2008R2 or 2012 indicate;

> If start_expression is less than 1, the returned expression will
>   begin at the first character that is specified in value_expression.

Yet the last column of my SQL statement above allows me to start at -1 and extract 6 characters.

Both servers I tried this on were running 2008 R2 (one (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) and the other R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64))

So my question is - What determines the version of SQL executed via SSMS? Is it the SSMS version itself, the database server, the database (one of the databases I executed this against was on a 2008 server in 2005 compatibility mode)?

Also, is the documentation wrong regarding start positions of 0 or less, or is my interpretation off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the database server you are connecting to is what matters. It is the server that interprets and execute your query.

As for the documentation it looks like there has been some confusion that has been fixed in SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012.

I can't find the quotes from the documentation you have in the question but I found this and the description of how many characters is returned is wrong in SQL Server 2008 but nowhere can I see that it should generate an error unless you specify a negative value as length.

---

[SQL Server 2008 SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19c808f-aaf9-4a69-af59-b1a5fc3e5c4c%28v=sql.100%29)

> If start_expression is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specifed in value_expression. In this case, the number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either the sum of start_expression and length_expression or 0.

---

[SQL Server 2008 R2 SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19c808f-aaf9-4a69-af59-b1a5fc3e5c4c%28v=sql.105%29)

> If start_expression is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in value_expression. In this case, the number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either the sum of start_expression + length_expression – 1 or 0.

---

[SQL Server 2012 SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19c808f-aaf9-4a69-af59-b1a5fc3e5c4c%28v=sql.110%29)

> If start is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in expression. In this case, the number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either the sum of start + length- 1 or 0.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The quote I posted is from SSMS 2008 BOL, so it is likely to be outdated and incorrect. I still think I am interpreting the doco wrong then, or it is simply incorrect. To say that _if start is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character in expression_ leads me to believe that `SELECT SUBSTRING(@Test, 0, 5)` should result in Hello. Is my assumption right, or am I missing something.

Comment: @MrMoose `substring('hello', 0, 5)` will start with the first character in the expression `h` and return `start + length - 1` number of characters which is `0 + 5 - 1 = 4` so you get `hell`.

Comment: Ahhh, re-reading it for a fifth time allowed it to sink in. So the length - 1 is only applicable in situations where start is less than 1. In cases of a positive start value, the length value is adhered to. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: By the way, if its of any use, the 2008 BOL URL showing the quote above saying it'll error if start_expression is less than 0 is ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10de_6tsql/html/a19c808f-aaf9-4a69-af59-b1a5fc3e5c4c.htm